# How to use Bitmap in Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin

I'm working on a Android app, I use firebase and kotlin. I am stuck at profile photo selection section. I can choose the image but can't create a bitmap. I'm following a guide for the app. Video I watched is kinda old probably something changed about the code and I can't make it work. Where can I find the solution. The suggested code is:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)
    
        register_button_register.setOnClickListener {
          performRegister()
        }
    
        already_have_account_text_view.setOnClickListener {
          Log.d(TAG, "Try to show login activity")
    
          // launch the login activity somehow
          val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
          startActivity(intent)
        }
    
        selectphoto_button_register.setOnClickListener {
          Log.d(TAG, "Try to show photo selector")
    
          val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
          intent.type = "image/*"
          startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
        }
      }
    
      var selectedPhotoUri: Uri? = null
    
      override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
          // proceed and check what the selected image was....
          Log.d(TAG, "Photo was selected")
    
          selectedPhotoUri = data.data
    
          val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
    
          selectphoto_imageview_register.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    
          selectphoto_button_register.alpha = 0f
    
          val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)
          selectphoto_button_register.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
        }
      }
```

Comment: Please describe what you expect and what goes wrong. There are third-party libraries like Picasso and Glide that make working with images like this easier.

Comment: I'm trying to pick a photo and show that photo in a circle button. I created button and i can choose the image but i can't show it in the circle. I tried to use mentioned code but Google might have changed something. That code doesn't work anymore

Comment: I mean specifically what is the problem? Does it crash? Is there a compiler error? Are the buttons arranged differently than you expect?

Comment: I don't how Bitmap works but when i wrote this code and run my app, i can choose the image but it doesn't show up on the button. In the tutorial video it works. Only difference in this line of code ""val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)  "" is  getBitmap word. There is a line in the middle of this word i don't know what that means. I hope i could explain :)

Comment: Is your "Photo was selected" message getting logged? The line through the method name means it is deprecated. In most cases, this means they recommend doing it differently in newer versions of Android. In a few rare cases, it means a method no longer works in later versions of Android if you're targeting them, but that isn't the case for this one (you can read the method documentation to see).